# how to import function in pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I am trying to create a `pytest` for a Python 2.x script executable with dashes included in its name. I tried to import it the usual way but I can't figure out how to make it work with the dashes.

My project structure is as follows:

```
package
    -- tests
    -- bin 
    -- subpackage
        -- ...py
```

Specifically, I need to test a function called `master_disaster()` which exists inside `bin/let-me-out` (yes with `-`). `let-me-out` is an executable `.py` file and my folder has no `setup.py` file or anything similar.

How can I import this function inside my test? My test is going to be a simple fixture that checks the time with:

```
@pytest.fixture
def now():
    return timezone.now()
```

It then uses the `now()` function to create a new file which `let-me-out` will delete after a specific amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, dashes make `let-me-out` word to an invalid identifier in Python. To work around it, you have to invoke the `imp` (Python 2.7) 
 or `importlib` (Python 3.5+) machinery.

#### Python 3.5+

Here is an example of importing a new module having a qualified name `let_me_out`, but using `bin/let-me-out` as source file:

```
import importlib


def test_master_disaster():
    loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('let_me_out', 'bin/let-me-out')
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
    let_me_out = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    loader.exec_module(let_me_out)
    # this is only a stub, to show an example of calling the master_disaster function
    assert let_me_out.master_disaster() == 'spam'
```

You can extract this code into a fixture to make it reusable:

```
import importlib
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def let_me_out():
    loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('let_me_out', 'bin/let-me-out')
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
    let_me_out = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    loader.exec_module(let_me_out)
    return let_me_out


def test_master_disaster(let_me_out):
    assert let_me_out.master_disaster() == 'spam'
```

#### Python 2.7

Things are even easier with Python 2.7:

```
import imp
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def let_me_out():
    return imp.load_source('let_me_out', 'bin/let-me-out')


def test_master_disaster(let_me_out):
    assert let_me_out.master_disaster() == 'spam'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to say but I am on Python 2.7 though.

Comment: @ahey I've added an example using `imp` on Python 2.7, check it out.