# How can I run pytest (and doctests) on Python files without .py extension?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

In some cases, for system scripts I like to keep the extension out and use a shebang. Unfortunately pytest seems to ignore these files and doctest fails because it cannot import these files. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# filename: "my-nagios-plugin"

import sys

def runcheck(value):
    """
    Example check

    >>> runcheck(3)
    0
    >>> runcheck(10)
    1
    """
    return 1 if value > 5 else 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(runcheck(int(sys.argv[1])))
```

Doctest output:

```
› python3 -m doctest my-nagios-plugin                                 ✗: 130
**********************************************************************
File "my-nagios-plugin", line 13, in my-nagios-plugin
Failed example:
    runcheck(3)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 1330, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest my-nagios-plugin[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        runcheck(3)
    NameError: name 'runcheck' is not defined
**********************************************************************
File "my-nagios-plugin", line 15, in my-nagios-plugin
Failed example:
    runcheck(10)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 1330, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest my-nagios-plugin[1]>", line 1, in <module>
        runcheck(10)
    NameError: name 'runcheck' is not defined
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   2 of   2 in my-nagios-plugin
***Test Failed*** 2 failures.
```

pytest output:

```
› pytest -m doctest-modules my-nagios-plugin my-nagios-plugin           ✗: 1
========================================= test session starts ==========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/users/malbert/work/monitoring-plugins
plugins: testinfra-3.4.0
collected 0 items

======================================== no tests ran in 0.21s =========================================
ERROR: not found: /home/users/malbert/work/monitoring-plugins/my-nagios-plugin
(no name '/home/users/malbert/work/monitoring-plugins/my-nagios-plugin' in any of [])

ERROR: not found: /home/users/malbert/work/monitoring-plugins/my-nagios-plugin
(no name '/home/users/malbert/work/monitoring-plugins/my-nagios-plugin' in any of [])
```

Comment: Have you tried to adapt [python_files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#confval-python_files) in `pytest.ini`?

Comment: Unfortunately setting `pytest.python_files` does not work :(

Comment: You are right - I just checked, pytest checks for the `.py` extension in `pytest_collect_files`, and if you overwrite `pytest_collect_files` the import of the test module via `__import__` fails. Looks like importing such a file is not possible in Python. I'm sure it's documented somewhere...

Comment: You will need to write your own collection logic, the most difficult part being the import since `my-nagios-plugin` isn't importable as a module at all, verify via e.g. `python -m my-nagios-plugin`. You'll need a custom `pytest_collect_file` hookimpl that creates a subclass of `_pytest.doctest.DoctestModule` that can import the script as `importlib.import_module` won't do. For the latter, I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49434295/2650249) with an example of importing scripts with dashed names.

Comment: @hoefling - maybe you can add this as an answer, as this this is not trivial (and quite interesting).  Have you considered to write a pytest blog? ;)

Comment: @MrBeanBremen haha, no, lacking profound english for blogging :-) Can't write thorough answers right now, submitting my thesis at the end of month, thus not much time for SO left.

Comment: I get the feeling that this isn't worth the hassle. If I end up with a script that has more LOC just for testing and import-magic than *real* code I must be doing something wrong ;) However, writing *real* unit-tests instead of doctests might be a good aproach for this. I was hoping for doctests as they implicitly add useful examples to the code-base.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me. It temp-copies it's own file contents to a `tempdir/orig_filename.py` and runs it in `pytest.main()`. A more-featured, commented, and detailed script found here:

https://gist.github.com/johnnyutahh/b38420c8095c3c9f66433ef11a7c9f0f

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tempfile, shutil, os, pytest, contextlib, sys
from pathlib import Path

@contextlib.contextmanager
def cd(newdir):
    prevdir = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(os.path.expanduser(newdir))
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(prevdir)

def main():
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        with cd(tempdir):
            selftest_file_path = \
                    Path(os.getcwd()) / f"{Path(__file__).name}.py"
            shutil.copy(__file__, selftest_file_path)
            pytest.main([selftest_file_path.as_posix()] + sys.argv[1:])

def test__basic_math1():
    assert 1 == 1

def test__basic_math2():
    assert 2 == 2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I like this idea. Unfortunately, this introduces a "pytest" dependency. The target system where the script will be deployed is mission critical and does not have third-party installs. In my case, I would need to run pytest only on the dev-machine and "from the outside" of the script. The script should only include stdlib imports.

Answer (score -1):

You could just leave the .py extension and then symlink to them from your system script directory.

Comment: This is not really a solution, but rather a workaround. I'm trying to keep these system files as self-contained as possible. Having them single-file scripts with no external dependencies makes it a lot easier for the sysadmin to deploy them wherever he likes without dealing with Python specifics. But I as a dev would love to run my unit-tests on them too ;)

Comment: @exhuma - I have the same desire/requirements. Related discussion here, with no "actual solutin" (besides the symbolic-link workaround mentioned above): https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/15dpvsm/singlefile_selftestingwithpytest_script_without/

Comment: Update: a nifty solution was found in the above reddit discussion. If I can find the time, I'll sometime-later work to post an appropriate answer here.

Comment: Done, answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76807763/605356